# Check if part of a string is present in keys of hash table

Tags: perl, hash

I'm dealing with a hash table in perl.

I have a multiple strings, with multiple lenghts and multiple `-`:

```
pre1-pre2-text1-text2
pre3-text3
pre4-pre5-pre6-text4
```

I have a `%hash` with the following keys:

```
pre1-pre2
pre3
pre4-pre5-pre6
```

So the keys `%hash` only contain the `pre` part of the strings.

How can I check if there is a match between let's say the first string `pre1-pre2-text1-text2` and the keys of `%hash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the inputs given by you in small perl code and i am able to check whether there is a match in keys

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my %langs = ( "pre1-pre2" => 'pre1-pre2',
 "pre3" => 'pre3',
 "pre4-pre5-pre6" => 'pre4-pre5-pre6');

@pats=("pre1-pre2-text1-text2", "pre3-text3", "pre4-pre5-pre6-text4");

for(keys %langs){
  foreach $ss (@pats){
    if (index($ss,$_) != -1){
      print("Key contains:",$_, "|", $ss,"\n");
    }
    else{
      print("NOT FOUND:",$_, "|", $ss,"\n");
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: If i have understood your requirement rightly then this will help you.

Comment: Some interesting coding choices here. Why `use warnings` but not `use strict`? Why declare `%langs` with `my`, but no other variables? Why switch between `for` and `foreach`? Why pass several arguments to `print()` instead of interpolating the variables into a single string? Why use `print()`, not `say()`?

Comment: And if this is the "correct" answer, which it very well could be, then hashes aren't really giving you anything. If you can't extract a key for O(1) lookup, then there's little point in the hash (at least as far as this goes), and you may as well use an array.

Comment: @DaveCross. Its been 8 years i have worked in Perl and so i searched for examples and created my example. So there will be some issues :)

Comment: @Raghuram: That's the problem with pulling together code from different sources. You can end up with wildly differing styles in the same example and that can easily confuse a beginner. Put yourself in the place of a beginner reading your code. I'd be thinking "so you use `for` to loop over a hash and `foreach` to loop over an array" - and that's just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

One way: form a pattern using alternation of keys, and test strings against it

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @strings = qw(pre-not pre1-pre2-text1-text2 pre3-text3 pre4-pre5-pre6-text4);

my %h = ( 'pre1-pre2' => 1, 'pre3' => 1, 'pre4-pre5-pre6' => 1 );

my $keys_re = join '|', map { quotemeta } keys %h; 

foreach my $str (@strings) { 
    say $str  if $str =~ /$keys_re/;
}
```

This has quadratic complexity, but alternation won't go through all keys and it's C (regex itself).

A possible improvement (or a necessity!) may be to suitably sort keys. For example, shortest first

```
my $keys_re = join '|', map { quotemeta } sort { length $a <=> length $b } keys %h;
```

This may help if there are keys with common parts, but note that it may be a non-trivial adjustment which can affect correctness -- and which *may be needed*; consider carefully.

To also get the key itself add the capturing parenthesis around the pattern

```
foreach my $str (@strings) { 
    say "$str matched by key: $1"  if $str =~ /($keys_re)/;
}
```

where `$1` contains the alternation that matched and was captured, which is the key.

Comment: Thanks. The if condition evaluates to true, so that seems correct. However how can I now print the match and access the value associated with that match in my original %h?

Comment: @user1987607 Welcome.  For that you want to _capture_ the match.  That's a good point, it should be in the post -- added a note.

Answer (score 1):

This answer supposes that `pre` cannot occure in the middle of the string (ie, you won't have a string like `pre1-pre2-text1-pre5` where your prefix would only be `pre1-pre2`). If this assumption isn't valid, then use `/^((?:pre\d+)(?:-pre\d+)*)/` instead of `/^(.*pre\d+)/` (I prefer the latter because it's more readable, but the former is more precise).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %pre = map { $_ => 1 } qw(pre1-pre2 pre3 pre4-pre5-pre6);

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($prefix) = /^(.*pre\d+)/;
    if ($prefix && exists $pre{$prefix}) {
        say "Prefix exists: $prefix";
    } else {
        say "Prefix doesn't exist: $prefix";
    }
}

__DATA__
pre1-pre2-text1-text2
pre3-text3
pre4-pre5-pre6-text4
pre7-pre8-text5
```

If you could have a line `pre1-pre2-text1` where the prefix should be just `pre1`, then this solution won't work. In that case, you'll have no other choice than to iterate over all the keys of the hash and check if they match the beginning of the string:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    for my $prefix (keys %pre) {
        if (/^\Q$prefix/) {
            say "Found prefix: $prefix";
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is far less efficient, since you need to iterate over all of the hash keys for each line.
Regarding `\Q`: it ensures that this solution works even if your prefixes contain special regex characters (like `+` or `.`). If you prefixes are always just like `pre1-pre2`, then you can omit `\Q`.

---

If you have trouble understanding `my %pre = map { $_ => 1 } qw(pre1-pre2 pre3 pre4-pre5-pre6);`: it's a concise version of

```
my %prev = (
    'pre1-pre2'      => 1,
    'pre3'           => 1,
    'pre4-pre5-pre6' => 1
);
```